# Stretch & Squish a Column DIV to the visible elements inside's width while SCROLLING

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As you scroll through the page, the blue background grows and shrinks to be close to the current section. In the video demo, when the section bounding-box top position arrives at 70% of the screen height, the background moves to that section.

Box1 = Left Col
Box2 = Right Col

So, while scrolling - The left col gets auto stretched/squished according to the elements inside displayed on the screen in the right col.

JSFiddle Trial: [CODE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/repmxcd7/)

[image: 10 SECOND VISUAL DEMONSTRATION]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.container-1 div {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box-1 .Lorem {
  top: 2vh;
  position: sticky;
}

.box-2 div {
  border: 1px rgb(2, 255, 2) solid;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box-2 caption {
  text-align: left;
}

.box-2 table {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.box-2 image {
  width: 100%;
}

.box-2 .Text {
  padding-left: 50%;
}

.box-2 .Text .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.box-2 .Text .btn:hover {
  background: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-2 .Text-2 {
  padding-left: 30%;
}

.box-2 .Text-2 .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.box-2 .Text-2 .btn:hover {
  background: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-2 image {}

.border-none {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

.border-none td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.border-none tr td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.border-none tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.topFixed {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
}

.topFixed span {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}


/* ============================================================================ */


/* ============================================================================ */

.backBtn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 7vh;
  right: 2vh;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  transition: width 0.1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.backBtn:hover {
  width: 15vh;
}

.backBtn span {
  opacity: 0%;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.backBtn:hover span {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 100;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
  <title>FLEX // TEST2</title>
  <link href="https://use.typekit.net/vha2sex.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="box-1">
      <div class="Lorem">
        <p style="font-size: 500%;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <br><br><br><br><br>

      <table class="border-none">
        <caption>ECC</caption>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 1</td>
          <td>Cell 2</td>
          <td>Cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 4</td>
          <td>Cell 5</td>
          <td>Cell 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 7</td>
          <td>Cell 8</td>
          <td>Cell 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 10</td>
          <td>Cell 11</td>
          <td>Cell 12</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="border-none">
        <caption>Elementary School</caption>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 1</td>
          <td>Cell 2</td>
          <td>Cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 4</td>
          <td>Cell 5</td>
          <td>Cell 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 7</td>
          <td>Cell 8</td>
          <td>Cell 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 10</td>
          <td>Cell 11</td>
          <td>Cell 12</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="border-none">
        <caption>Middle School</caption>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 1</td>
          <td>Cell 2</td>
          <td>Cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 4</td>
          <td>Cell 5</td>
          <td>Cell 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 7</td>
          <td>Cell 8</td>
          <td>Cell 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 10</td>
          <td>Cell 11</td>
          <td>Cell 12</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <div class="Text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Button</span>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="Text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Button</span>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="Text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Button</span>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="Text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Button</span>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hMrkGV8.png" alt="" width="500px"></img>
      </div>

      <div class="Text-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Button</span>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="Text-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Button</span>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="Text-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Button</span>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="Text-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
          <div class="btn">
            <span>Button</span>
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="wideParagraph">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
          sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
          dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
          sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
          dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
          sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
          dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
          sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
          dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
          sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
          dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
          sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
          dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
  <div class="backBtn">
    <span>Back</span>
  </div>
  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
  <!-- A <div> tag that follows the class: "topFixed" - It is a fixed white bar on the top of the screen that doesn't go away while scrolling. -->
  <!-- It contains a <p> tag, with "Sitename" - As shown in the demo video. -->
  <div class="topFixed">
    <span>Sitename</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if the right column is actually changing size in that video. It looks more like the blue box is just growing and covering the right box based on the width of the div in that container. The right boxes content never actually squishes it just gets covered by the blue box.

Comment: You're right - I am trying to do it in JavaScript, and cannot achieve it yet... I need help in this.

Comment: I updated the code to make it smoother and added your html and css. here's a new CodePen https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/WNRqdgr. I also added a snippet in my answer below. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very rough idea of what you want. You can start here and smooth things out. The code could probably be refactored to be better but it should be understandable for you.

EDIT: Updated

```js
let lc = document.getElementById("left_container");
let rc = document.getElementById("right_container");
let tc = document.getElementById("table_container");
let text1 = document.getElementById("text_container");
let text2 = document.getElementById("text2_container");
let wideText = document.getElementById("wideParagraph");
let dogPic = document.getElementById("image1");

let percent = rc.getBoundingClientRect().height*0.7;

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    lc.style.width = tc.getBoundingClientRect().x-10+"px";
});

rc.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let tcBounds = tc.getBoundingClientRect();
  let text1Bounds = text1.getBoundingClientRect();
  let text2Bounds = text2.getBoundingClientRect();
  let wideTextBounds = wideText.getBoundingClientRect();
  let dogPicBounds = dogPic.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (tcBounds.y + tcBounds.height/2 > 0) {
    lc.style.width = tcBounds.x-10+"px";
  } else if (text1Bounds.y < percent) {
    lc.style.width = text1Bounds.x-10+"px";
  }
  if (dogPicBounds.y < percent) {
    lc.style.width = dogPicBounds.x-10+"px";
  }
  if (text2Bounds.y < percent) {
    lc.style.width = text2Bounds.x-10+"px";
  }
  if (wideTextBounds.y < percent) {
    lc.style.width = wideTextBounds.x-10+"px";
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#left_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 30vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.05s linear;
}

.Lorem > p {
  font-size: 500%;
}

#right_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#table_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 4em;
}
.border-none {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}
.border-none td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.border-none tr td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.border-none tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
#text_container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 35%;
  width: 55%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
.Text {
  white-space: wrap;
}
.Text .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.Text .btn:hover {
  background: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#image1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#dogPic {
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
#text2_container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  width: 65%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
.Text-2 {
  white-space: wrap;
}
.Text-2 .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.Text-2 .btn:hover {
  background: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#wideParagraph {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 3%;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

.topFixed {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
.topFixed span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Courier New;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
.backBtn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 6%;
  right: 3%;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  transition: width 0.1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.backBtn:hover {
  width: 15vh;
}

.backBtn span {
  opacity: 0%;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.backBtn:hover span {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 100;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="left_container">
  <div class="Lorem">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="right_container">
  <div id="table_container">
    <table class="border-none">
      <caption>ECC</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
        <td>Cell 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 7</td>
        <td>Cell 8</td>
        <td>Cell 9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 10</td>
        <td>Cell 11</td>
        <td>Cell 12</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="border-none">
      <caption>Elementary School</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
        <td>Cell 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 7</td>
        <td>Cell 8</td>
        <td>Cell 9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 10</td>
        <td>Cell 11</td>
        <td>Cell 12</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="border-none">
      <caption>Middle School</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
        <td>Cell 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 7</td>
        <td>Cell 8</td>
        <td>Cell 9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 10</td>
        <td>Cell 11</td>
        <td>Cell 12</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="text_container">
    <div class="Text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
      <div class="btn">
        <span>Button</span>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="Text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
      <div class="btn">
        <span>Button</span>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
      <div class="btn">
        <span>Button</span>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="Text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
      <div class="btn">
        <span>Button</span>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="image1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hMrkGV8.png" alt="" id="dogPic" />
  </div>
  <div id="text2_container">
    <div class="Text-2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
      <div class="btn">
        <span>Button</span>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="Text-2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
      <div class="btn">
        <span>Button</span>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Text-2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
      <div class="btn">
        <span>Button</span>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="Text-2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eaque suscipit quia debitis voluptatibus corrupti ducimus, hic quis aut doloribus cupiditate facilis ut numquam. At! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Repellat sint magnam recusandae excepturi reiciendis ab voluptatem culpa soluta, hic tenetur expedita id quos beatae quas?
      <div class="btn">
        <span>Button</span>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wideParagraph">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
      sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
      dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
      sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
      dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
      sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
      dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
      sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
      dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
      sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
      dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita reiciendis culpa exercitationem nam, accusantium odit similique quas nisi vero quo esse molestias alias dicta a eaque consectetur dolore sit ex iste! Cum quia, praesentium fuga
      sit saepe, fugit id nam tenetur excepturi quas similique eaque amet ad soluta aliquid, repellendus esse odit illum delectus hic qui vel! Alias adipisci nulla voluptate suscipit cupiditate dolore amet quae temporibus vel harum officia blanditiis
      dolorem expedita quos similique eaque, maiores molestias aspernatur error vitae est, magni quidem? Dignissimos vitae aut enim recusandae ducimus velit. Aspernatur atque voluptatibus quaerat ipsum laboriosam exercitationem, quae facere.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<div class="backBtn">
  <span>Back</span>
</div>
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!-- A <div> tag that follows the class: "topFixed" - It is a fixed white bar on the top of the screen that doesn't go away while scrolling. -->
<!-- It contains a <p> tag, with "Sitename" - As shown in the demo video. -->
<div class="topFixed">
  <span>Sitename</span>
</div>
```